# How to use JPA findById for querying on CompositeKey?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have the following `IdClass`

```
public class EmployeeId implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = -2221228212747288530L;

  private String id;

  private long joiningDate;
}
```

and `EntityClass`

```
@Entity
@IdClass(EmployeeId.class)
private class Employee {
  
  @Id
  private String Id;

  @Id
  private long joiningDate;

  //rest of columns   

}
```

How do I use `findById` here with only Id column? I have already tried `findByIdId`, `findByTransportOrderIdId`. Not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply create a method `findById` that only takes a `String` as parameter:

```
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, EmployeeId> {

    Optional<Employee> findById(String id);
}
```

Comment: This is not working, It says the ```Provided id of the wrong type for class Entity.class Expected: class IdClass.class. got class java.lang.String expected IdClass.class```

Comment: And you created this method in the Repository? You cannot use the provided method from JpaRepository

Comment: Yes I created this method in Repository only. Adding @Override over the function makes it work somehow.

Comment: Which Spring Boot Version do you use?

Comment: I've added the whole EmployeeRepository in the answer. This works with Spring Boot 2.5.6

Comment: Yes, It's working. Thanks Simon, Can you help me understand what did we really do? Did we just override ```findById``` method of CrudRepository ?

Comment: No we don't because it has another parameter. So it's simple Java method overloading

Comment: Yes got it. Thanks Simon